# When to pick *aus-* vs. *an-* in German verbs

Tags: verb

Many verbs, like *bauen* or *braten* can be combined with *an-* to form verbs like *anbauen* or *anbraten*. However, in some cases there are variants of these verbs that take *aus* for example *ausbauen* or *ausbraten*.

Is there any rule for deciding whether a verb takes *aus* or *an*? They appear to mean exactly the same, though in some cases one would (conventionally?) say *Wein ausbauen* rather than *Wein anbauen*, but in other cases one would say *Kartoffeln anbauen* rather than *Kartoffeln ausbauen*. Or is this related to dialects from the speakers?

Comment: "aus" and "an" look similar but that's all. They are not closer related than any other pair of prefixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are separate verbs. One can try to deduct the meaning from the built-in preposition but there are transferred meanings involved which don't seem reasonable at first glance. Or maybe not even anytime later.

> bauen (to build)
>
> anbauen (to attach something (by building); to grow fruits and vegetables)

The preposition **an** means *tight to*, so attaching something is straight forward. But why *grow fruits and vegetables*? NO ONE KNOWS.

> ausbauen (to add interior; to intensify; to refine)

The preposition **aus** means *out of*. Why is adding interior, intensify or refine *out of*? NO ONE KNOWS.

Uh, and by the way, wine is also being ***an**gebaut*. That means to grow the vines. While ***aus**bauen* means to refine the product by putting it in storage for months to years before selling.

---

And of course, a whole range of prepositions and other prefixes can be combined with *bauen*, too:

> einbauen (to build something into something else)
>
> abbauen (to remove something previously attached)
>
> umbauen (to rebuild something)
>
> überbauen (to build something on top of an older structure in the ground)
>
> zubauen (to close the last gaps by building)
>
> erbauen (to construct)
>
> verbauen (to build too much stuff into a compartment)
>
> vorbauen (to prepare oneself)

etc etc.

Treat them all as separate verbs. And for all the other verbs, too.

Comment: "The preposition **an** means *tight to*, so attaching something is straight forward." - well, another common meaning of the *an* prefix in verbs is that the action is just started, not completed to its end (antesten, anbrechen, ...). And yet another one refers to the state of something being "(switched) on" (anschalten, anmachen, angehen, ...).

Comment: "Treat them all as separate verbs." - in one way, yes. But, as pointed out in my above comment, there are indeed various common meanings for prefixes that can also help to deduce the meaning of a verb. The tricky part is that often, "prefix + root" is either an "official" combination with a specific meaning where the meaning of the prefix may be non-obvious or deviate from the general case, or "prefix + root" is *not* an "official" combination, in which case the combination can *still* be formed ad-hoc, with the prefix using its common meaning (or one of them, if there are more than one).

Comment: Yes, of course, *an* has several other meanings as well, but neither of them matches growing fruits etc. And about the meaning of these prepositions can help deducting the meaning of the verb: That's what I wrote in the very second sentence.

Comment: "but neither of them matches growing fruits" - I'm not so sure about that. You don't build fruits, but you "lay their foundations". Thus, you *start* their construction process, which could well match with the first meaning of "an" that I outlined in my comment.

Comment: *Ich baue **auf** meinem Acker Kartoffeln **an**.* If it was all covered by *an*, why would there be another preposition *auf* needed?

Comment: Because prepositions and verb prefixes are used independently of each other, even though sometimes they may look the same and have a similar meaning. *Ich baue **hinter** meiner Garage einen Lagerschuppen **an**.* Additional prepositions can always be required depending on what you want to say, no matter what verb prefix was used with what meaning.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Verb prefixes *resemble* prepositions, but they aren't prepositions.

Comment: I never claimed that, and I never claimed the verb prefix somehow covers the information provided by the preposition.

Comment: @Janka: the verb is "anbauen". "Ich baue an" is a conjugation of the same verb, "to grow". Where do you grow? For instance on a field. So "ich *baue* **auf** meinem Acker Kartoffeln *an*" means "I *grow* potatoes **on** my field".

Comment: @Janka: they not only *resemble* prepositions, they are *derived* from prepositions. Often, the meaning of the preposition is somehow related to the meaning of the verb prefix, although through the times, that relation may have changed a lot and the prefix may have got a meaning of its own. But even if I hear a German word with a prefix I didn't know before, the prefix usually tells me what the meaning of the word is. For instance the prefix "zer-" often means something destructive, and the prefix "ver-" indicates change. "An-" often means adding something, and "ent-" indicates removal. Etc.

Comment: +1 for the advice to treat them all as separate verbs. Yes, there are some guidelines (semantics of the prefix), but also way too many exceptions/idioms to allow these guidelines to be called actual "rules".

Comment: "Anbauen" as "grow" is so idiomatic for example that, as you can see, not even native speakers are entirely sure about how to derive it. "Verbieten" or "entscheiden" would be examples of "ver-" and "ent-". The prefixes kinda hint at the meaning, but it's really hard to come up with the correct meaning of the whole word on the fly when combining them with their roots. And so on.

Comment: According to [Grimm'sche Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=Anbau) "anbauen" as "to grow" seems to be the older meaning then "to build".

Comment: Actually the correct translation of "anbauen" is "to plant", not "to grow".

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/anbauen So they are wrong then?

Answer (score 1):

It can be reasoned by two meanings: place or time.

Examples for "place":

- *anbauen*: you put something **there** (either to grow sth. (put the seed/plants in the ground) or to mount (add another piece), German: etwas da her**an** bauen

Examples for "time":

- *ausbauen*: you **continue** to build, means **out** of a certain time **until the end**
- *anbraten*: you **start** to roast (the beginning, German: **An**fang)
- *ausbraten*: you **continue** to roast, means **out** of a certain time **until the end**

You see (especially with anbauen/anbraten) there is not logical rule which one is used, it has developed historically, you just have to learn the vocabulary. This answer just gives you a certain background for the reasons.